# How to lazily stream using HttpServletRequest#getPart(name)

Tags: servlets

I'm using Jetty 9's implementation of [`HttpServletRequest#getPart(name)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPart%28java.lang.String%29), and it appears to eagerly processes the entire request (or at least the `Part` in question) before continuing, even though the resulting `Part` exposes a `getInputStream()` method.

Is there a way for `getPart` to return immediately, and leave request streaming to the resulting `Part`'s `InputStream`?

For reference, here's the relevant snippet from my `Servlet` implementation:

```
override def doPost(req: HttpServletRequest, res: HttpServletResponse) {
  println("ABOUT TO GET PART") // this happens immediately
  val file = req.getPart("file")
  println("GOT PART") // it takes a long time to get here if the upload is large
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's wicked tedious, but this can be done using [MultipartStream](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/MultipartStream.html) from [commons-fileupload](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/):

```
try {
   MultipartStream multipartStream = new MultipartStream(input, boundary);
   boolean nextPart = multipartStream.skipPreamble();
   OutputStream output;
   while(nextPart) {
     String header = multipartStream.readHeaders();
     // process headers
     // create some output stream
     multipartStream.readBodyData(output);
     nextPart = multipartStream.readBoundary();
   }
 } catch(MultipartStream.MalformedStreamException e) {
   // the stream failed to follow required syntax
 } catch(IOException e) {
   // a read or write error occurred
 }
```

This requires the use of the `InputStream` from `HttpServletRequest#getInputStream()`, and the boundary delimiter encoded in the HTTP request's content type:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------bd019839518ca918
```